# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS freezes every time I run my IDE and browser

Tags: freeze, crash, system, intellij

The problem happens when I run **intellij** **idea** and two different browsers **Firefox** and **brave**

I am using `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`

And here is my hardware information

```
     *-memory
          size: 8GiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          ...
          version: 6.142.10
          size: 3462MHz
          capacity: 4200MHz
          width: 64 bits
```

Answer (score 0):

That machine is too lightweight to run IntelliJ plus two browsers, this is nearly a six year old CPU. IntelliJ is a beast of an app, and while they pretend that it will run on anything it will run potato on POTATOES.

You may consider switching your development to using vim, nvim, or vscode. VSCode uses a lot of ram, but it's pretty light on the CPU.

There is a long shot possibility of course in that your CPU is not going into turbo mode at all either due to being disabled in bios or thermals (over-heating).

The other long shot is that you're using an encrypted disk partition either in combination with a high cpu using filesystem (xfs, zfs, or btrfs). Anytime you'd use the files on those partitions on an old PC you'll be in stop-motion.